# Cannot reference items in select for join

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have not been able to figure out scope of reference when there are nested queries.  For example I can't seem to reference NoCarsFound.CU in my inner join.  I don't understand why in my join I can't reference previous result sets...I think I just don't undrestand the scope of referencing previous select results or referencing aliases in my inner join's ON comparisons.

I also get Ambiguous column name 'CU'

So I keep getting errors saying it doesn't know NoCarsFound.CU.  I even tried to reference a straight view such as vwInvalidCars.CU, and it doesn't understand vwInvalidCars either.

```
create procedure [Rac].[GetCarStatDetails_sp]
    @Year int,
    @CarTitle varchar(30),
    @Company varchar(31),
    @CU varchar(12),
    @UserName varchar(50)
as
BEGIN

DECLARE @CarMatch table
(
    FaceValueTol varchar(100),
    FaceValueDesc varchar(100),
    Year int,
    CU varchar(16),
    PaintTypeDesc varchar(50)

)

insert into @CarMatch
    Select  temp1.FaceValueTol,
            temp1.FaceValueDesc,      
            temp1.Year,
            temp1.CU,
            temp1.PaintTypeDesc
    from    Rac.viewCarBase as temp1  
    join (select Username, userCars.CU from Nep.viewUserCars userCars where UserName = @UserName) as userCars on userCars.CU = temp1.CU
    INNER JOIN
    (
        Select  CU,
                from Rac.vwCarFactor carfactors
        where RiskFactorTypeID not in (334,553,34334,534,7756)
        Group by    CU
    ) as temp
    on 
        and temp1.CU = temp.CU 
        and temp1.PaintTypeDesc  = temp.CalcPaintTypeDesc 
    Where
        temp1.RiskFactorTypeID=4
        and temp1.[Year]=@Year
        and (temp1.CarTitle=@CarTitle or @CarTitle='<All>')
        and (temp1.CU=@CU or @CU='<All>')

SELECT  ProductID_bo,
        Coalesce(CarTitle_bo,LTRIM(RTRIM(CarTitle))) as CarTitle, 
        Coalesce(Company_bo,LTRIM(RTRIM(Company))) as Company, 
        Coalesce(CU_bo,LTRIM(RTRIM(CU))) as CU
    FROM
        Rac.viewCarBase as NoCarsFound
        join (select Username, userCars.CU from Nep.viewUserCars userCars where UserName = @UserName) as userCars on userCars.CU = NoCarsFound.CU
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        Select  ProductID_bo,
                CarTitle_bo, 
                Company_bo,
                CU_bo,
        from (
                SELECT  ProductID as ProductID_bo,
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(CarTitle)) as CarTitle_bo, 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(Company)) as Company_bo, 
                FROM    Rac.viewCarBase
                join (select Username, userCars.CU from Nep.viewUserCars userCars where UserName = @UserName) as userCars on userCars.CU = Rac.viewCarBase.CU
                where   ProductID in (Select ProductID from @CarMatch) and
                        and (CarTitle=@CarTitle or @CarTitle='<All>')
                        and (Company=@Company or @Company='<All>')
                        and (CU=@CU or @CU='<All>')

            ) AS SUB1

        Group By    
                    CarTitle_bo, 
                    Company_bo,
                    CU_bo,
        ON
                NoCarsFound.CU = CarsFoundDeals.CU_bo
    where 
        and (CarTitle=@CarTitle or @CarTitle='<All>')
        and (Company=@Company or @Company='<All>')
        and (CU=@CU or @CU='<All>')

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at the two following pieces of SQL from what you have above:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    Select  ProductID_bo,
            CarTitle_bo, 
            Company_bo,
            CU_bo,
    from (
            SELECT  ProductID as ProductID_bo,
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(CarTitle)) as CarTitle_bo, 
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(Company)) as Company_bo, 
            FROM    Rac.viewCarBase
            join (select Username, userCars.CU from Nep.viewUserCars userCars where UserName = @UserName) as userCars on userCars.CU = Rac.viewCarBase.CU
            where   ProductID in (Select ProductID from @CarMatch) and
                    and (CarTitle=@CarTitle or @CarTitle='<All>')
                    and (Company=@Company or @Company='<All>')
                    and (CU=@CU or @CU='<All>') --<--HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        ) AS SUB1
```

and

```
where 
    and (CarTitle=@CarTitle or @CarTitle='<All>')
    and (Company=@Company or @Company='<All>')
    and (CU=@CU or @CU='<All>') -- <--HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Both of these appear to be referencing `CU` in a way that could potentially cause the error you are reporting.

Comment: You need to specify which tables `CU` column  you are referencing.  For instance if `Rac.viewCarBase` has the `CU` column change it to `Rac.viewCarBase.CU`

Comment: Yea I finally see why.  Because the other areas I reference BU I'm referencing it via an alias or some object but here it's just plain BU so the compiler has no clue where BU comes from...since the rest have aliases on them, this must too...